# Run Ant multiple times using a different property file each time

Tags: java, xml, xslt, ant, rss

I have an Ant project that uses a property file as input to:

1. Retrieve a specific RSS feed and store it
2. Via several targets, uses XSL to eventually output an XML API call.

The property file has not only the specific feed to go get, but 8 other text and date values that are needed for the API call.

The Ant + XSL solution works great, and is fast.

The problem:
I have 8 different property files.  I would like to run Ant (cmd line for now) once, and have Ant loop through the entire set of targets 8 times, once for each property file as input.

What's the best Ant method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: simply .bat or .sh script does not work for you?

Comment: Ant, by design, doesn’t do loops, unless you’re willing to make use of ant-contrib to make Ant behave more like a shell script.  Sergei is right, just use the system’s shell for the loop.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not a .sh scripter, but yes, thought of doing .bat if I can't find a looping mechanism within Ant, which is strange....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`<ant>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task to execute the build with different properties. Configure a target that executes all 8 of the different ant runs, and then run that. Something like this:

```
ant runAll
```

Would execute the "run" target 8 different times with their specific properties file loaded for that execution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project basedir="." name="" default="run">
  <target name="runAll">
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file1.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file2.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file3.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file4.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file5.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file6.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file7.properties"/>
      </ant>
      <ant inheritAll="false">
          <property file="file8.properties"/>
      </ant>
  </target>
    <target name="run">
        <echo message="running..."/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was working on a solution very similar yesterday using Antcall instead of your suggestion of just using multiple <ant...> calls.  I'll try.

Comment: Mads, I based my solution on your suggestion, thank you!  I did change it a bit, by adding to each <ant> call an antfile attribute, which refers to another file that contains all of the targets that do the main processing:

    <code><ant antfile="subbuild.xml" inheritAll="false">
            <property file="properties_1.txt"/>
    </ant>